# How to read external table with bigquery storage api?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bigquery-storage-api

I'm trying to read an external table using `bigquery` storage api in python, and got the error message:

```
"Only external tables with connections can be read with the Storage API."
```

The source data is a `csv` file in Google cloud storage.
I've created a spark connection, and granted the service account I'm using to authenticate BigQuery Connection User, but still hitting the same error.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: There are notes on external tables here ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage#limitations   if you have "simple" external tables it wont work ... but instead use BigLake.